# Missing $ inserted with apacite?

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\title{For testing}

\begin{document}

Information about natbib in \citeauthor{sharelatex}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibli.bib}

\end{document}
```

This gives the error "Missing $ inserted". What has mathmode to do with apacite or citeauthor?

Comment: Check if there aren't any `$` in your `bibli.bib` file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you share your .bib file?

Comment: Further to @PhelypeOleinik 's comment, anything that could cause TeX to enter mathmode in a `.bib` entry (e.g., underscores) could cause this.  But without looking at the specify `.bib` entry, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @samcarter This is the only content in my bib file: @misc{sharelatex, title={ShareLaTeX, the Online LaTeX Editor}, url={https://nl.sharelatex.com/learn/Natbib_citation_styles}, journal={ShareLaTeX, Online LaTeX-verwerker}}

Comment: @AlanMunn See my answer above. 
BTW, Is it possible to reply to multiple anwers :) ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `_` in the url, which can normally only be used in math mode. In order to use them in a url, either use the `url` or the `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\usepackage{url}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{sharelatex, 
    title={ShareLaTeX, the Online LaTeX Editor},
    url={nl.sharelatex.com/learn/Natbib_citation_styles},
    journal={ShareLaTeX, Online LaTeX-verwerker}
} 
\end{filecontents*}


\title{For testing}

\begin{document}

Information about natbib in \citeauthor{sharelatex}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```