# How to get rid of lots of natbib warning?

Tags: natbib, texshop

Again when I run my `main.tex` file, LateX prompts up with number of lines which has following pattern:

`` Package natbib Warning: Citation `piaget1973understand` on page 47 undefined on input line 44. ``

`Underfull \hbox (badness 1000) in paragraph at lines 44--45`

and at the end:

```
Appendix A (./mainchapters/appendix.tex) (./main.bbl [49] ./main.bbl:43:Missing  $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.43 ...s?id=com.google.android.apps.seekh\&hl=en_us.
?
```

`main.tex`

```
documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\date{02 March 2020}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}


\chapter*{Dedication}

To my parents.

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that...

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{chapters/abstract_v2}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction_v2}

\chapter{Children Computers and Constructionism}
\input{chapters/chapter1_v1}

\chapter{Design methodologies for children's technology}
\input{chapters/chapter2_v1}

\chapter{Toys of 21st Century}
\input{chapters/chapter3_v1}

\chapter{Child Computer Interaction in Developing countries}
\input{chapters/chapter4_v1}

\chapter{Current scenario}
\input{chapters/chapter5_v1}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\input{mainchapters/appendix}

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{/Users/pythonbuddha/Documents/Thesis/References.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Missing $ inserted` is an error, not a warning. You don't show the relevant part of your document, but based on the message, it looks like you need to escape the `_` in `...android.apps.seekh\&hl=en_us`. (See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416656/)

Comment: @DisenchantedLurker, thank you. May I ask please how to find the targeted file which contains error?  I am new to Latex!

Comment: Option A: try clicking on the error text; depending on your LaTeX editor, it might take you straight to the problematic line (I don't use texshop, so I'm not sure if it can do this). Option B: since the error mentions `main.bbl`, it's probably in your references (`.bbl` is a bibliography-related file). Do a `Ctrl+F` (or whatever the "Search" shortcut is) and search for `hl=en_us` in your `References.bib` file.

Comment: Since the error isn't in the main file, copy `main.tex` under another name, and comment out all the input statements.  Uncomment them one by one and run the job for each.  The one that produces the error is the file where the problem is located.